# How sizeof Operators Works inside the IF Statement in C

Tags: c

```
int main()
{
     if (sizeof(int) > -1 )
           printf("True");
     else
           printf("False");
     return 0 ;
}
```

I expected the program results in "True" but after executing it results in "False". Could anyone explain why this is the case?

Comment: What did you find out the `sizeof` **operator** yields? Which type? And format this mess properly. Read [ask]. A modern compiler should warn about this comparison. If not, enable all recommended warnings (at least `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion`). And alway fix the cause for warnings before asking.

Comment: In C, the sizeof operator inside the if statement works exactly as it works outside the if statement.

Answer (score 3):

sizeof returns size_t, which is unsigned.

Comparison unsigned and signed numbers needs an attention in C, because of such comparison usually gives surprising results for beginner programmers, as we can see here.

Basically, -1 gets converted to a very big unsigned int, so your condition is false.

Comment: The result is not "surprising", but well defined.